# Victory Charts with multiple lines and tooltips

Tags: css, reactjs, victory-charts

I am making a graph which must zoom and display tooltips for each data point. In Victory's documentation there is a [multi-line chart with tooltips](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/gallery/voronoi-tooltips-grouped) however if you adjust the data set, the tooltips overlap. I found that VictoryPortal is a mechanism for overcoming this but it appears that even in the linked example, it is using VictoryPortal. (The tooltip's props has `renderInPortal: true,`)

To overcome this I created a second VictoryGroup after the Lines/Scatters which was just Scatters of **all** the data sets combined and gave them `opacity: 0` so it *looked* like you were hovering the original Scatter dot. This approach works but feel like there must be a better, cleaner way that I'm missing here. I couldn't figure out how to make a snippet work with Victory so here's the code in question:

Method for rendering Lines/Scatters for individual data sets together in a group:

```
renderLine = (m, i) => (
this.state.s[i]
  ? <VictoryGroup
    key={i}
    color={m.color}
    data={m.data}
    labels={(d) => `y: ${d.y}\nx: ${d.x}`}
    labelComponent={
        <VictoryTooltip
          cornerRadius={0}
          style={{ fontSize: 10 }}
        />}
    >
      <VictoryLine />
      <VictoryScatter size={(d, a) => a ? 8 : 3} />
    </VictoryGroup>
  : null
)
```

And my render method:

```
render() {
const { renderLine } = this
return (
  <div style={{ width: '50vw', margin: '0 auto' }}>
    <VictoryChart
      height={400}
      width={400}
      padding={30}
      containerComponent={<VictoryZoomContainer />}>
      <VictoryAxis
        domain={{ x: [-180, 180] }}
        standalone
        label={'Angle (°)'}
        style={axisStyle}
        crossAxis={false}
        orientation={'bottom'}
        axisLabelComponent={
          <VictoryLabel orientation={'top'} y={'97%'} verticalAnchor={'end'} />
        }
        gridComponent={
          <Line
            style={{
              ...axisStyle.grid,
              transform: 'translate3d(0,100%,0)'
            }}
          />
        }
        tickCount={12}
        tickLabelComponent={<VictoryLabel dy={-5} />}
      />
      <VictoryAxis
        dependentAxis
        orientation={'left'}
        label={'Discriminiation (dB)'}
        axisLabelComponent={
          <VictoryLabel orientation={'left'} x={15} />
        }
        standalone
        offsetX={30}
        style={axisStyle}
      />
    {masterData.map((d, i) => renderLine(d, i))}
    <VictoryGroup
      color={'rgba(0,0,0,0)'}
      data={[...dataSet, ...dataSet2, ...dataSet3, ...dataSet4]}
      labels={(d) => `y: ${d.y}\nx: ${d.x}`}
      labelComponent={
          <VictoryTooltip
            cornerRadius={0}
            style={{ fontSize: 10 }}
          />}
    >
      <VictoryScatter size={(d, a) => a ? 8 : 3} />
    </VictoryGroup>
    </VictoryChart>
</div>
);
}
```

Any input or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I started with a similar solution but finally I had some successful results with the VoronoiContainer component and using the tooltip from there.

https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-voronoi-container/

You have to put a VoronoiContainer as a containerComponent in VictoryChart.

With that method the VictoryScatter is unnecessary.